# CSS not being applied to data returning from WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

I am using `gatsby-source-wordpress` to fetch data from my wordpress site into my gatsby site. The data is being fetched easily, but the CSS is not being applied to it.
For example my query is

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allWpPost {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          content
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

The title is being fetched perfectly of each post but the content that is being written is in plain text format like

```
<h6><strong>Fasces of lorems for ipsums</strong></h6>
<img loading="lazy" class="size-medium wp-image-11347 alignleft" src="http://deeptem.com/agency2free/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/agancy_single_01-5-241x300.jpg" alt="" width="241" height="300">
```

so I converted that plain text to html using

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.content }} />
```

Now the doc is being displayed in HTML format but without any css

**EDIT**
Most probably its because it can't find wordpress classes such as `wp-image-11347`. How can I get access to these classes

Comment: Where is the CSS being hosted? In other words, are you saying that CSS from your WP theme isn't being applied, or CSS from your Gatsby app?

Comment: CSS from WP theme is not being applied

Answer (score 1):

When you use Gatsby with WordPress, you should think of WordPress as nothing more than a drawer where you store your things (in this case, your things are mostly HTML content). What Gatsby does is take what you ask for from the drawer, put it in its data layer, and assemble it into a webpage you've built using React.

So, to your question - the reason the CSS from your WordPress theme isn't being applied is that *your WordPress theme is no longer a part of the equation*. WordPress has become a 'headless CMS' (CMS stands for content management system) and Gatbsy/React is how you're going to display everything from the drawer that you've asked for, in your case `content` and a `title`.

I'm not super familiar with the WordPress API, so there may be a way to query for CSS files (for some reason I doubt it) - if not, you'll be responsible for styling any HTML content you get from WordPress, just like any other regular old React app!